# Why i cant use bitmap class on dll class?

Tags: vb.net, class

For example:

```
Public Class Class1
   Public Sub Some()
       Dim Image As New Bitmap("C:\image.bmp")
   End Function
End Class
```

Displays an error on Bitmap which says "Name Bitmap is not declared".

Some solution? is impossible use Bitmap class or another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referencing the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly and importing the `System.Drawing` namespace?

Right-click on the `Bitmap` identifier and see if Visual Studio asks you to add an import for it.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio provides the functionality that you suggest; I guess you are using ReSharper?

Comment: I slightly changed my answer. It does have functionality to add namespace imports, though I think you're right that it doesn't support adding assembly references automatically.

Comment: Lol sorry, stupid question i see x3.
Yep, it doesn't support that.